# How to reverse arp using nping for Windows

Tags: networking, arp, nmap

I would like to send a reverse ARP to resolve an IP address given a MAC address using [nping for Windows](http://nmap.org/nping/).

The documentation is not clear on how this should work and I'm unable to find any examples online. Can anybody assist?

Here is what I have tried:

```
C:\>nping --arp --arp-type rarp-request --arp-target-mac 00-AA-BB-CC-DD-EE
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts pinged.

C:\>nping --arp --arp-type rarp-request --arp-target-mac 00-AA-BB-CC-DD-EE 10.10.10.10
Starting Nping 0.6.47
SENT (0.1560s) RARP who is 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE? Tell 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
SENT (1.1560s) RARP who is 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE? Tell 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
SENT (2.1560s) RARP who is 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE? Tell 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
SENT (3.1560s) RARP who is 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE? Tell 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE

Max rtt: N/A | Min rtt: N/a | Avg rtt: N/A
Raw packets sent: 5 (210B) | Rcvd: 0 (0B) | Lost: 5 (100.00%)
```

Comment: Please do not [double post](http://superuser.com/q/877768/212612).  Rather pick the site that you feel will give you the best answer and post there.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not answering your question with using nping only.
I believe you can achieve what you’re  looking for by typing :

> nping --rate=5 ***172.16.5.0-255*** & arp -a | findstr
>   "***ec-f4-bb-6a-91-9c***"

The first command pings all hosts in **your subnet** to update your ARP table, the second prints the table and filters **the mac** you're looking for.

Please note that you can not reverse lookup a host that belongs to a different subnet.

Comment: That is a good method of performing an ARP scan, but that's not the same as a reverse-ARP.

Comment: Agree but my understanding is that the protocol (rarp) is obsolete, so you would have to come with a workaround like mine to get what you want.

Comment: In the same fashion if you do not want to update your ARP table :        netsh dhcp server \\<DHCP_Server> scope <NetworkAddr> show clients 1 | findstr <MAC>